# Ошибка redirect_uri при oauth2 vk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth2

Прошу помочь, долго уже сражаюсь с ВКонтактом и OAuth2, в facebook все гладко - здесь проблемы. Задеплоил сайт на heroku, адрес - http://mysite.heroku.com, домен, соответственно, mysite.heroku.com (просто без протокола), redirect_uri 
 ---http://mysite.heroku.com/chat_rooms и --https://mysite.heroku.com/chat_rooms.

В dev режиме все работает норм, тесты зеленые. А вот

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"redirect_uri is incorrect, check application redirect uri in the settings page"}

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Вы посмотрите для начала, какой `redirect_uri` в запросах от браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Если тип вашего приложения - standalone, то redirect_uri должен быть равен https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html

Взято из официальной документации VK API - https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user?f=1.1.%20Redirect%20uri

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?